# Calling react function in electron ipcRender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am trying to call the following function from react with ipc.renderer

```
componentDidMount() {
    ipcRenderer.on('log-out', function () {
       localStorage.setItem('user', 'null');
       this.forceUpdate();
    });
}
```

but every Time i call it I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.forceUpdate is not a function
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (App.js:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:96)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191)
```

What am I doing wrong or how it suppose to be done ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ipcRenderer.on('log-out', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('user', 'null');
        this.forceUpdate();
    });
}
```

The `this` in `this.forceUpdate();` is not the `this` you are looking for. To fix the problem, you need to bind `this` to the corresponding context (your component), as:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ipcRenderer.on('log-out', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('user', 'null');
        this.forceUpdate();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Or creating a closure using the `this` to `self` like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    self = this;
    ipcRenderer.on('log-out', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('user', 'null');
        self.forceUpdate();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that but now I am getting this error and another one ipcRenderer.on(...).bind is not a function

Answer (score 1):

That's the very common issue of fat arrow.

Here you can read more about fat arrow ([here](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/))

***We can solve this by 2 ways:***

---

### First:

*Replace this:*

```
function () {
```

*with:*

```
() => {
```

---

### Second:

```
ipcRenderer.on('log-out', function () {
   localStorage.setItem('user', 'null');
   this.forceUpdate();
}).bind(this);
```

---